# How to iterate through entity properties Doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, entities

Dectrine created entities. i.e. User
To be able to input users in db I have this model's setUser():

```
function setUser(){
    /**
     * @var Users $user
     */

    $user=new Users();

    $user->setFirstName($this->input->post('first_name'));
    $user->setLastName($this->input->post('last_name'));
    $user->setEmailAddress($this->input->post('email_address'));
    $user->setUsername($this->input->post('username'));
    $user->setPassword($this->input->post('password'));

    try{
        //save to database
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());

    }
    return true;
}
```

Instead of declaring each setter I want to Iterate through all properties.
How can I achieve this?
something like:

```
$array=$user->eachProperty;
```

Just to get an array with:
Array(FirsName,Lastname,EmailAddress)
That's it. I'm just looking for the Doctrine function basically.

So that I can Iterate and can create setters automatically.
THanks.